# Does Sharepoint 2013 Support SAML 2.0?

Tags: claims-based-auth, security-token-service

As SP2010 does not support SAML 2.0, I want to know if SP2013 supports SAML 2.0 tokens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that SP2010 and SP2013 both support/utilize WIF (Windows Identity Foundation) for claims-based authentication.  (semi) Recently, there was a WIF extension released to support the SAML 2.0 protocol.

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/card/announcing-the-wif-extension-for-saml-2-0-protocol-community-technology-preview)

With some tinkering you *may* be able to get something working.  I should note that I looked into this for SAML 1.1 but only found this support for SAML 2.0, so this is where my limited knowledge on the subject unfortunately ends.  Also, you should note the difference between the SAML protocols and the tokens (protocol utilizes the tokens but sometimes you only need support for the tokens themselves).  It was my finding that the tokens were better supported than the protocol.  You may be able to work with the tokens even without the above extension.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342186/windows-identity-foundation-does-not-officially-support-saml-2-0-use-wif-ctp-or

Answer (score 4):

I think SharePoint doesn't support SAML v2.0 even we are talking about WIF. I tried to handle SAML 2.0 token in SharePoint but unfortunately it seems that doesn't work so far, like SharePoint engine can't do that ;/

Answer (score 4):

SharePoint 2013 only supports SAML 1.1. [source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262350.aspx#suppauth)

Answer (score 2):

SP 2013 also does not support SAML 2.0 protocol and assertions. Because as explained in earlier reply, it is not released by MS in WIF.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Online now supports SAML 2.0 . Check this [blog](http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/06/announcing-support-for-saml-2-0-federation-with-office-365/) for same. Also this [post](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj679342.aspx) shows the different identity providers which are supported.